# VSCode - Tasks version 2.0.0 : how to use the "output" console, not the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a task at version 0.1.0 that I try to migrate to 2.0.0.

This task simply transpiles Typescript to Javascript using a Gulp script. The output is shown in the "output" console, there is no terminal involved and I want it to keep it that way (mostly because of the infamous message "`Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`" at the end of any command in the terminal!).

I can't see how to migrate this task to version 2.0.0 so no terminal is involved!

Here's the version **0.1.0** :

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "compile",
            "args": [
                "compile",
                "exit"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my current try for version **2.0.0** :

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "identifier": "compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "taskName": "compile",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "command": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gulp compile exit",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This *does* show the output in the integrated terminal.

How can I make it use the **output console** instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try change `"reveal": "always",` to `"reveal": "never",`

Comment: I have the same problem. Any working solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using the tasks panel is the recommended way to go, but if you really need to use the output panel. You'd need to implement a [CustomExecution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider#customexecution) and get the output of your command. Then to write to the output panel, first you would need to create a dedicated output channel and write to it:

```js
let outputChannel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel('channelName');
outputChannel.appendLine('message');
```